# Does anyone know any useful gem to create voting system in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, acts-as-votable

Hi I am creating a small Sinatra app and trying to create a voting system in it.

I tried using acts_as_votable gem but it is giving me some error.

```
rake db:migrate                                                                                                                                  
rake aborted!                                                                                                                                         
TypeError: ActsAsVotable is not a class
```

Here is my migration file which I tried to make from source code of gem.
class ActsAsVotable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def self.up
    create_table :votes do |t|

```
  t.references :votable, :polymorphic => true
  t.references :voter, :polymorphic => true

  t.boolean :vote_flag
  t.string :vote_scope
  t.integer :vote_weight

  t.timestamps
end

if ActiveRecord::VERSION::MAJOR < 4
  add_index :votes, [:votable_id, :votable_type]
  add_index :votes, [:voter_id, :voter_type]
end

add_index :votes, [:voter_id, :voter_type, :vote_scope]
add_index :votes, [:votable_id, :votable_type, :vote_scope]


end

  def self.down
    drop_table :votes
  end
end
```

I also created Acts_as_votable module from the gem source code. Please see below code

```
require 'active_record'
require 'active_support/inflector'

$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))

module ActsAsVotable

  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    require 'acts_as_votable/extenders/votable'
    require 'acts_as_votable/extenders/voter'
    require 'acts_as_votable/vote'
    ActiveRecord::Base.extend ActsAsVotable::Extenders::Votable
    ActiveRecord::Base.extend ActsAsVotable::Extenders::Voter
  end

end

require 'acts_as_votable/extenders/controller'
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  include ActsAsVotable::Extenders::Controller
end
```

Any suggestion to make this work or any other alternet solution for Sinatra?

Comment: Don't know of any gem, but check this: https://github.com/andisugandi/poting, it may help you.

Comment: Please read "[ask]". You're asking us to recommend off-site resources, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [the "Acts As Votable" documentation](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable), it's a gem integrated with the Rails framework, so I would not bet on it working correctly with Sinatra (even though you use ActiveRecord Migrations).

In the end you can either switch to Rails or write the voting code yourself; you can see an example posted by Gerry or try "[Create your first voting app with Sinatra](http://guides.railsgirls.com/sinatra-app)".

Comment: Thank you so much. As I am really a newbie to all of this stuff, I was not 100% sure if any way to make this work. But your answer makes sense. Thanks a lot.